# Flutter layout -3 column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a resume document similar to the attached image. Need some help on top-level layout

Would it be:

```
container

   children

      column widget

          children

              container (header)

              container (body)

                 children

                     column

                        children

                           row (education)

                           row (experience)
```

also, how would I get the dotted lines?

Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be:

```
container

   children

      column widget

          children

              container (header)

              container (body)

                 child

                     row

                        children

                           column (education)

                           column (experience)
```

For Dash Lines, you can use the following Plugin [Flutter Dash](https://github.com/huy-lv/flutter_dash)

Another alternative would be:

```
column widget

     children

          Row (header)

          Row (body)

             children

                column (education)

                column (experience)
```

To achieve the exact layout in the body section, you might want to use to `Expanded` Widget to achieve what you want.

```
column widget

     children

          Row (header)

          Row (body)

             children

                Expanded [Flex 1]

                     child

                           Container (education)

                Expanded [Flex 2]

                     child

                           Container (experience)
```

For `Dash` to work:

You need to add `flutter_dash: ^0.0.1` under `dependencies` in pubspec.yaml

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dash/flutter_dash.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) => MyApp2(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyApp2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
            )
          ],
        ),
        Dash(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            length: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            dashLength: 12,
            dashColor: Colors.red),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Text('Education'),
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Dash(
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                length: (2 *MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 3 - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                dashLength: 12,
                dashColor: Colors.red),
            Expanded(
              child: Text('Experience'),
              flex: 2,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
 ...your document...
    Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: ....header....,
              ),
          Container(
            ...body...
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
            child: ...education...
                    ),
                Container(
                  child: ...experience...,
                    ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to get the dash lines

Comment: I wrote a small piece of code to implement the dash plugin above.